# Calling other DB methods within TransactionScope in C#

Tags: c#, transactions

I'm using a number of transaction database operations within a project, and would like to make use of `TransactionScope` to combine them all such that the whole thing can be rolled back easily.

For the sake of clarity, I would like to encapsulate each operation within a separate method.

When using a `TransactionScope`, are methods called from within it which create a database connection included as part of the scope, as shown below.

```
     public void RunDBTransactions() {
        try {
            using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) {
                RunOperationsOnFirstDB();
                RunOperationsOnSecondDB();

                transactionScope.Complete();
            }
        } catch (TransactionAbortedException tae) {
            // Aborted
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Deal with any other issues
        }
    }

    private void RunOperationsOnFirstDB() {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectString)) {
            connection.Open();

            //Carry out database operations here
        }
    }

    private void RunOperationsOnSecondDB() {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectString)) {
            connection.Open();

            //Carry out database operations here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are all the methods in the same class? If so, you can make the `_transactionScope` a private field of the class, initialize it in the constructor, and call `_transactionScope.Dispose()` in the class' `Dispose()` method (you'll have to implement `IDisposable` for this).

Comment: @LewsTherin In which case, how would the transaction scope be aware of the methods called within it? Is it just a case of all database connections established within the scope of the TransactionScope object will be included in it? If so, that could be exactly what I'm looking for... assuming that I put the call to my class implementing the transactions in a `using` block itself to enforce the dispose, or deliberately dispose it when done.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if the transactionScope would be aware of all the methods called within your class. I would test it out and see if all the changes that take place in all of your methods are rolled back. Wrapping the call to your custom class in a `using` block should do the trick (provided you implement `IDisposable` in your custom class and dispose the transactionScope as I mentioned above).

Comment: @LewsTherin I'll give it a try and let you know. I can't rationally see why it wouldn't work though...